# How to Run a jar file which contains clojure and java code compiled class files. java file contains main method

Tags: java, clojure

**java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main compile.clj** this is compiling the clojure code.
**javac CalculateSum.java** compiling java code.
**jar cvf sum.jar *.class** getting jar file of class files.

**java CalculateSum** is running main and giving output correctly.
How to run jar file from java environment? 
like **java -cp clojure.jar;sum.jar clojure.main CalculateSum** where CalculateSum is main class.

**sample code**
_*utils.clj*_

`(ns utils

    (:gen-class :name Utils
    :methods [#^{:static true} [sum [java.util.Collection] long]]))
    (defn sumx [coll] (reduce + coll))
    (defn -sum [coll] (sumx coll))`

**compile.clj**

`(set! *compile-path* "./")
    (compile 'utils)`

**CalculateSum.java**
`public class CalculateSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.List<Integer> xs = new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>();
    xs.add(10);

    xs.add(5);
    System.out.println(Utils.sum(xs));
  }
}`

**Aim is to craete jar file out of this code. and run jar file**

**java should call clojure code, execute it and print result**

Comment: It's not clear whether *all* the classes are no in jar files, and also whether or not the jar files contain manifests stating the main class, classpath dependencies etc. Some sample code would be useful.

Comment: @JonSkeet i have edited the question, now you can see the code also.

Comment: But no sign of a jar file manaifest. It's also not clear where the compiled clojure code is ending up - are you including that in the jar file too?

Comment: compiled class files of utils.clj and CalculateSum.java are added to jar file, i don't have anything like __manifest__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so there are two things:

- To run it just *from* a jar file rather than making it an executable jar file, you should be fine with just:

  ```
  java -cp sum.jar CalculateSum
  ```

  or possibly (if it needs classes from closure.jar at execution time)

  ```
  java -cp closure.jar;sum.jar CalculateSum
  ```
- To turn it into an executable jar file which you can run with

  ```
  java -jar sum.jar
  ```

  you'll need a [manifest](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) file including a Main-Class attribute letting you set the [entry point](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html), and possibly a Class-Path attribute to [add the closure.jar file to the jar's classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html).

Follow the links for more details.